# Oracle JDBC connecting to the wrong user

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using hibernate(3.6.9.Final) and oracle 11g databse with jdbc(ojdbc6:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver)
my connection string is jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVERNAME:1521:ORCL
datasource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource

ioc:spring 3.0.7.RELEASE

server: tomcat 6

The description of my problem is:
I have two schemas(users) defined in my oracle server
MY_SC and MY_OLD_SC, 
MY_OLD_SC represents an older schema of my application and has table MY_TABLE with one column name MY_ID
MY_SC is the latest schema of my application and also has MY_TABLE but in addition to MY_ID column it has also MY_NAME column

When i start my application with the MY_SC user and hibernate on validate I fail on the following exception:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: MY_NAME in MY_OLD_SC.MY_TABLE

it seems that it connects to the wrong schema even though i verified that i connect with MY_SC user, only after i drop the MY_OLD_SC from the database i'm able to connect to MY_SC.

This issue is not consistent sometimes i'm able to work with different schams, but when it fails once then i must drop all the schemas in the database except the one that i want to use.
most of the times it happens after i use impdp of a new schema, but not not only after the impdp

please note that if i connect with sql developper the connection to the user seems to be correct.

statement for creating the users:

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY username
       DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS  
       TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
       QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;


GRANT conn TO username;
```

code for impdb:

```
./impdp system/pass@orcl remap_schema=org_name:new_name directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR TRANSFORM=oid:n dumpfile=backup.dmp
```

Will be great if you'll know what might be the problem, maybe I need to create the user differently? what could cause this issue?

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently with Hibernate 3.3.0. Basically, the Hibernate database metadata scanner that runs during validation will pick up any table that matches your entity's definition regardless of which schema it comes from as long as it has read access to the table definition (not necessarily read access to the table itself). It gets them in alphabetical order so if your entity is for table `WIDGET` and your target schema is `MY_APP_SCHEMA` but there's another `WIDGET` in `ANOTHER_APPS_SCHEMA`, the one from `ANOTHER_APPS_SCHEMA` will be used by Hibernate to validate the entity.

I wasn't able to find anything official on Hibernate's site but did find similar posts [here](http://www.schakko.de/2014/01/07/hibernate-uses-wrong-schema-during-schema-validation/) and [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1027459).

You may be able to use `hibernate.default_schema` to set the schema for Hibernate to use.

Comment: Thanks Chris, -Dhibernate.default_schema=MY_USER solved this for me.  Very peculiar that Hibernate does this.  I'm using 3.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner way to point hibernate to the default schema - use environment property on server startup. On java jvm use:

```
-Dhibernate.default_schema=YOUR_SCHEMA
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is setting the **hibernate.default_schema** property to fit your user (in your persistence unit or as env property as TomaszZ. pointed out).

Other solution is revoking privileges to access the other schemas for your user. This should not be allowed also beacuse of petential security issues (unless such access it's required for that particular user).